# Raspberry Pi 3, 64bit Suse and Monero

Tags: full-node, raspberry-pi

I know a lot of issues that people encounter running Monero nodes on rPis is due to the 32bit OS.

I was planning to use this:https://en.opensuse.org/HCL:Raspberry_Pi3
(A 64bit version of Suse) and run a full node.

Anyone tried that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pi 3 is still not a decent system, even with a 64bit OS. Their chip lacks AES instructions. Will be slow at verifying blocks.